# Wicket ModalWindow: click outside modal to dismiss

Tags: jquery, wicket, modal-window

I need to add a behavior to `ModalWindow` such that when a user clicks outside of the modal, if a certain condition is met (checked server-side in my `respond()` method), the modal is dismissed.

I tried implementing something based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042426/wicket-close-modalwindow-on-keypress). The problem is that I can't attach a click listener to the modal window div because it's not added to the DOM until the modal is shown (the example attaches a `keyup` to the document itself.)

I thought of extending `ModalWindow` and adding the JS via `getShowJavascript()`, but then I don't have any means to connect it to an `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.respond()` method for the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the behavior not to the modal, but rather to the widget I add to the modal via `ModalWindow.setContent()`. When my widget is added to the modal, the mask div is present in the DOM, and I can then successfully attach a click handler.

To wit:

```
public static class CloseModalOnOutsideClickBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior
{
    private final ModalWindow modal;

    public CloseModalOnOutsideClickBehavior(ModalWindow modal)
    {
        this.modal = modal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        if (myConditionIsMet()) modal.close(target);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
    {
        response.renderJavascriptReference("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js");
        response.renderJavascript("" +
                "$(document).ready(function() {\n" +
                "  $('div.wicket-mask-dark').bind('click', function(evt) {\n" +
                        getCallbackScript() + "\n" +
                "        evt.preventDefault();\n" +
                "  });\n" +
                "});", "closeModal");
    }
}
```

Note that I'm somewhat precariously depending on the modal window's mask having a class named "wicket-mask-dark"; this may not be the case if you alter the CSS settings used by `ModalWindow`.